# How do I create pyramid tiles from .ecw file?

Tags: gdal, ecw

I have an `.ecw` file. I want to pyramid this file and use in my app. How Can I do it with `GDAL`?

**Note:** My file is greater then 4 GB.

Comment: ECW files contain *internal* overviews, you shouldn't need to ever update them because they're not generally editable.. if you have an ECW editor it should update the overviews on save. The cutoff for 'free' ECW creation is 50MiB measured by rows x columns x bands, anything larger than that you will need to purchase a license.

Comment: How can I read this `internal overviews`?

Comment: You don't. If you're building an application with GDAL (or other API) it will do it for you; it's in the DLL file for the driver. If you want a tileset then use the GDAL2Tiles.py utility http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html but first make sure your python is installed and working properly with your GDAL.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Can you show an example?

Comment: No, from the application side there's nothing to see when reading an ECW for display. As for GDAL2Tiles.py I've not used it much as I don't do web development.